# Deploy PHP application from Azure DevOps to AWS using CI/CD pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I'm able to deploy the ASP.net applications from Azure DevOps to AWS environments using CI/CD pipeline YAML file. I modified the ASP.net YAML file a bit and tried to deploy the PHP application.  But it didn't worked out.
Below is the modified YAML that I'm using to deploy PHP application.
Can some one help to figure out the issue in this? Am I missing any steps/ settings?

```
# PHP
# Test and package your PHP project.
# Add steps that run tests, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/php

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  phpVersion: 7.2

steps:
- script: |
    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phpdbg /usr/bin/phpdbg$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar$(phpVersion)
    php -version
  displayName: 'Use PHP version $(phpVersion)'

- script: composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist
  displayName: 'composer install'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
- task: BeanstalkDeployApplication@1
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'AWS_Creds'
    regionName: 'us-north-1'
    applicationName: 'app_name'
    environmentName: 'env_name'
    description: 'New Build from Azure DevOps'
    applicationType: 'version'
    webDeploymentArchive: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/WebApp.zip'
```

I'm getting the below error when I run the above pipeline script.

```
Starting: composer install
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.182.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/f5188f9d-a102-4093-ad5d-0acaaa110763.sh
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /home/vsts/work/1/s
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: composer install
```

Comment: Well, it can't find the `composer.json` in the working directory. Without knowing how the working state looked like, how are we supposed to figure out what you changed to break it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can I know the tasks required to deploy PHP application from Azure DevOps to AWS env?

Comment: And how can I add composer.json file in the working directory using CI/CD pipeline. The script  'composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist' is a default one provided by Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

> > Composer could not find a composer.json file in /home/vsts/work/1/s

The **/home/vsts/work/1/s** is the working directory where your repository will be checked out. If your composer.json file is under the root directory of repository, that is, its path is `repsotiory_name/composer.json`, the [Command Line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) will successfully run this command `composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist`.

If the composer.json file is under the sub directory of repository, you need to switch current directory to its file path. For example, its path is `repsotiory_name/subfolder/composer.json`, below script should work as expected.

```
- script: |
    cd subfolder
    composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist
  displayName: 'composer install'
```